# how to add API value to a list?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is the API response

```
[
   {
     "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "unit_number": "101",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "1bhk",
    "unit_space": "500",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
   },
   {
    "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "unit_number": "102",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "2bhk",
    "unit_space": "900",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
    },
    {
    "building_name": "alzimar",
    "unit_number": "103",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "1bhk",
    "unit_space": "500",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
    },
]
```

1. I wanted to add "building_name" to a list
2. The same name should not repeat

I tried this way but not working

```
static List<Map<String, String>> choices = <Map<String, String>>[
    {
        "title": building_name, "id": building_name
    },
];
```

am calling the value like

```
child: Text(choice["title"],),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
List apiResponseList = [
   {
     "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "unit_number": "101",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "1bhk",
    "unit_space": "500",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
   },
   {
    "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "unit_number": "102",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "2bhk",
    "unit_space": "900",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
    },
    {
    "building_name": "alzimar",
    "unit_number": "103",
    "unit_type": "flat",
    "sub_type": "1bhk",
    "unit_space": "500",
    "annual_rent": "25000",
    "annual_rent_in_word": "twenty five thousand "
    },
 ];
```

Then map `apiResponseList` into the new list:

```
List<Map<String, String>> choices = [];

  for (var item in apiResponseList) {
    if (choices.isEmpty) {
      choices
          .add({"title": item['building_name'], "id": item['building_name']});
    } else {

    //This adds the map only if `choices` does not contain the same `building name`
      if (choices.any((test) => test['title'] != item['building_name'])) {
        choices
            .add({"title": item['building_name'], "id": item['building_name']});
      }
    }
  }
```

If you run `print(choices)`, you'd get

```
[{title: Burj Khalifa, id: Burj Khalifa}, {title: alzimar, id: alzimar}]
```

Comment: but value repeating!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it only checking and trimming first two arrays.remain all building values repeating https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l1l668gh20pfu7/Screen%20Shot%202020-08-07%20at%2012.00.42%20AM.png?dl=0